# SQL Group By where no row has value

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

What is the best way to write this query:

SELECT ID FROM table 
WHERE **"no row with the ID has a created date > '1/1/2012'"**
GROUP BY ID

In summary, I only want to see grouped ID's where every row has a created date > '1/1/2012'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `having` clause and look at the maximum created date:

```
SELECT ID
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MAX(CreatedDate) <= '2012-01-01'
```

Comment: did you mean Min(createddate) > 1/1/2012

Comment: @RandallMathews . . . It depends if you go by the second sentence or the third in the question.  Yes, either `MIN()` or `MAX()` works, depending on what the OP really wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (table where date > '2012-01-01') group by id
```

Comment: This still returns back records of "ID" that have date < '2012-01-01'. I only want ID's where none of their rows have date < '2012-01-01'

Comment: the where clause should work although the group by won't work because no summary function is being used in the select.  The having clause will do what you want.